# Python - Increment time by random variable

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to increment a time by a random number of minutes. The time is 09:50 and I'd like to increment it by between -5 minutes or +5 minutes. This will be stored as a function. Currently I'm converting my time into seconds since the epoch, then multiplying it by a random variable. However, this changes the value way too much. My code is below:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
from datetime import datetime
import time

time_leave = int(time.mktime(time.strptime('2018-08-22 09:50:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
time_leave_dist = uniform(.9,1.1)
x = datetime.fromtimestamp(time_leave * time_leave_dist.rvs())
print(x)
2023-08-16 01:08:59.542477
```

I'm unsure how to convert the random variable from a percentage into time. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where does multiplication come in? From your description, it sounds like you want to add or subtract from the time.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say "increment" in place of multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use random to generate a random number in that range, and add it as minutes:

```
import random
from datetime import timedelta
increment_delta_minutes = timedelta(minutes=random.randint(-5, 6))
x = x + increment_delta_minutes
```